# Rewrite rule for opening a different page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm stuck with some `.htaccess` rules.

I've got the page `/module/slug`. I want, when I type `slug` to see content of `/module/slug/` but not redirect to this page. Is it possible? I've tried this rule, but had no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^slug/$ /module/slug/ [L]
```

My `.htaccess` content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^calculator/$ /sample-page/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: what you mean with "content of /module/slug/". Directory listing?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you don't tell Apache to redirect (`R=301`).

Add the redirect flag `R`, and it should work. Also make sure that:

1. You have set the `RewriteBase` correctly.
2. There are not any other rules earlier in the file that match the same URL.

.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^slug/$ /module/slug/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unforunatelly it doen't work. Add my .htaccess content

Comment: @user3013494 I have added some details to my answer. Your rule just comes too late, it needs to be set earlier than the WordPress rules.

Comment: This rule redirect me to the page /module/slug/, but I want to keep url /slug, but show content of the page /module/slug/

Comment: @user3013494 In that case it depends on how the page on `/module/slug/` evaluates the URL to select its content. And then the .htaccess might be the wrong tool for that.

Comment: this is 2 different pages like index.php?p=111 and index.php?p=222